# Scroll content over background image?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, mobile

Im making a website for mobile devices with jQuery Mobile, HTML and CSS and I've just set a background image. 
I want the image to stay the same while scrolling the rest of the content over it.
I guess its "background-attachment: fixed" I should use and that works on my computer but not on my phone.
On my phone the content scrolls together with the background image, which is not what I want.
My browser on the phone is Safari since its an iPhone and on the computer I use Opera.
Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe your iPhone's Safari doesn't support that...

Answer (score 0):

`fixed` wont work in the mobile. And here is the link for  detailed explanation to make that work in mobile http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/01/developing-a-responsive-website-background-images/

You can try with `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Ive tried with cover and that indeed puts the image in the position I want but I doesnt make it fixed behind the rest of the content. But I shall check the link out.